# Print Progress Bar for Apt

Tags: bash

I came across a way to [enable a progress bar](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar) for apt and apt-get, and for scripting purposes, I'm trying to print only that progress bar. I haven't had any success with grep (`grep "Progress:"`) or tail (`tail -1`). Is this possible? Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar likely doesnt print to stdout.

Try shifting it via `2>&1 | grep Progress:`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are simply trying to find only the progress bar within the apt or apt-get code, so you can make use of it later, then there is no guarantee that it is named `Progress:`, or that the prompt containing `Progress:` is even in the script you are searching. It is likely `sourced` from another file.

You can try opening the script in an editor like `vim` or `kwrite` or `jot`, etc. and looking within the script for where the meter is called and go from there. There is no telling whether it will be under `scale`, `meter`, `percent`, etc...

In the absence of finding anything, you can always use something simple. There are many available on the web. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

## string of characters for meter (60 - good for 120 char width)
str='▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒'

tput civis                  # make cursor invisible

for i in `seq 1 100`; do    # for 1 to 100, save cursor, restore, output, restore
    printf "\033[s\033[u Progress: %s %3d %% \033[u" "${str:0:$(((i+1)/2))}" "$i"
    sleep 0.1               # small delay
done

printf "\033[K"             # clear to end-of-line

tput cnorm                  # restore cursor to normal

exit 0
```